# Css background in layout

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, background-color

I would use a background for my layout.
I'm programming a Rails app and i'm not good with CSS.
This is my actual page:

[image]

As you can see , there are: banner,main,column and footer.
I used this CSS:

```
    /*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the file
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.

 *= require_self

 *= require jquery-ui

 *= require_tree .

*/




#container{
        //centered layout
        margin-left: 10em;
        margin-right: 10em;


        #banner {
            /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#eeeeee+0,cccccc+65 */
            background: rgb(238,238,238); /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 65%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(238,238,238,1)), color-stop(65%,rgba(204,204,204,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 65%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 65%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 65%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 65%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
            height: 160px;

            padding: 30px;

            border-bottom: 2px solid;

            font: small-caps 20px/20px "Times New Roman", serif;

            color: black;

            text-align: left;





            img {

                float: left;

                margin-top: -10px;

            }



            p {

             text-align: right; 

             font-weight: bold;

            }



            c {

             color: orange;

            }



        }



        #notice {

            color: #000 !important;

            border: 2px solid red;

            padding: 1em;

            margin-bottom: 2em;

            background-color: #f0f0f0;

            font: bold smaller sans-serif;

        }



        #columns {

            background: #EAF7FF;


            #main {

                margin-left: 17em;

                padding: 2em;

                background: white;

            }



            #side {

                position: absolute;

                color: black;

                float: left;

                padding: 1em 2em;

                width: 13em;

                background: #EAF7FF;



                img{

                    width:50px; /* you can use % */

                    height: auto;

                }



                a:hover{

                    background:none;

                }



                a:hover {

                    color: black;

                }


                ul {

                  padding: 0;



                    li {

                        list-style: none;

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        #footer {
            background-color: red;
        }
}
```

My HTML page is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


    <head>

      <title>Salinas</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag   "application", :media => "all" %>

        <%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>

      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    </head>





    <body class="<%= controller.controller_name %>">
        <div id="container">

            <div id="banner">

            </div>



            <div id="columns">

                <div id="side"> 

                <div class="btn-group-vertical">



              </div>

            </div>



            <div id="main">

             <% if notice %>

                 <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>

             <% end %>

             <% if alert %>

                 <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>

             <% end %>



             <%= yield %>


            </div>

            <div id="footer">   
                        dwdwdwdw

            </div>  

        </div>


    </body>

</html>
```

i would have this result:

[image]

(i would have the external green background)
Can you help me?

EDIT: I obtained this result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your stylesheet:

```
html{
    background-color:#A8E519; /* change background color to green */
}
```

Comment: Try setting the same colour as `background-color` on `#container`?

Comment: in that case i don't see any change

Comment: Is this an app running in a web browser? Can I access it to debug?

Comment: Why don't you give the body tag the `background-color: green;`?

Comment: no , unfortunally is in local. @Phil M. green or #A8E519 give me the same result in the body tag.

Comment: @PhilM. HTML is the parent of body, although it makes no real difference in pratice, google around for a full explanation.

Comment: @Vito running on localhost, but you're viewing in a browser? Have you tried chrome/safari developer tools to inspect the element?

Comment: i tried the native tool of firefox , but don't understand much

Comment: I see, all I can suggest is to read up on Firefox dev tools and try to inspect the element/s causing the white area: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_CSS